# Pass socket into a component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Here is the `App.js` of React Native 0.59 app.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Event from './src/components/event/Event.js';
import Chat from './src/components/chat/Chat.js';
import GLOBAL from "../../lib/global";

//socket.io
const socket = io(GLOBAL.BASE_URL, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  jsonp: false
});

//create the navigator
const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Event:  Event,
    Chat: {
      screen: Chat,
      
    } 
  }, {
    initialRouteName: "Event"
  }
);

//export it as the root component
export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

The `socket` needs to be passed into `Chat` component. Since there is only Chat component using the `socket`, I would like to pass `socket` as props instead of using `context` which shares data among many components. Ideally the `socket` can be passed in `createStackNavigator` like this:

```js
const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Event:  Event,
    Chat: {
      screen: Chat, params: {socket: this.socket}            
    } 
  }, {
    initialRouteName: "Event"
  }
);
```

How to do that with `React Native 0.59`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of is to create a new component which returns Chat component and socket as a prop.

**Example**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Event from './src/components/event/Event.js';
import Chat from './src/components/chat/Chat.js';
import GLOBAL from "../../lib/global";

//socket.io
const socket = io(GLOBAL.BASE_URL, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  jsonp: false
});

const ChatWithSocket = () => (<Chat socket={socket} />)

//create the navigator
const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Event:  Event,
    Chat: {
      screen: ChatWithSocket,

    } 
  }, {
    initialRouteName: "Event"
  }
);

//export it as the root component
export default createAppContainer(navigator);
```

Comment: simple and yet efficient!. Many thanks. There are 2 more props for `Chat` when called In `Event` component. `this.props.navigation.navigate("Chat", {eventId: id, user: this.state.user})` . How to add those 2 somewhere in the process for Chat? I can pass the socket into Event and then pass it to Chat. But I would like not to touch Event if I can do it with Chat.